# Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided - WebStorm

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I've this error, I'm using WebStorm.

```
/src/Component/Professori.tsx
Type error: Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.  TS1208
```

I've also added the flag marked as false into tsconfig.json in this way

```
    "isolatedModules": false
```

Comment: Can you include your `setupProxy.js`? Also what IDE are you using? VS Code?

Comment: @UlugToprak I'm using WebStorm. I resolved the error commenting the line "isolatedModules": false that was initially marked on true

Answer (score 0):

You should use the export keyword post to your component declaration, that in order to be aligned to the ECMAScript standards when declaring a public component. so it should look like that:

```
const professori  = (props: any) => (
  ...
);
export default professori;
```

this will resolve the error.